# Create multi-level menu for Treeview width recursive

Tags: recursion, javafx, menu, treeview

I have the following database

[image]

I use Map For general information group father

```
public static Map<String, List<TblCategory>> mapHierarchy() {
        Map<String, List<TblCategory>> mapHierarchy = new HashMap<>();
        try {
            prepareStatement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM `TblCategory` ORDER BY `name`");
            resultSet = prepareStatement.executeQuery();
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                TblCategory TblCategory = new TblCategory();
                TblCategory.setID(resultSet.getString("parentID"));
                List<TblCategory> memberHierarchy = mapHierarchy.get(TblCategory.getParentID());
                if (memberHierarchy == null) {
                    memberHierarchy = new ArrayList<>();
                    mapHierarchy.put(TblCategory.getParentID(), memberHierarchy);
                }
                TblCategory.setName(resultSet.getString("name"));
                memberHierarchy.add(TblCategory);
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(HierarchyServices.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return mapHierarchy;
    }
```

I use the map to create a multi-tiered menu,I do not know how to perform here's what I'm continuing to do

```
CheckBoxTreeItem cbtHierarchy;
CheckBoxTreeItem<String> cbtNameParent;
CheckBoxTreeItem<String> cbtName;
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
   Map<String, List<TblCategory>> mapHierarchy = HierarchyServices.mapHierarchy();
        mapHierarchy.forEach((String t, List<TblCategory> u) -> {
            showHierarchy(t, u, cbtHierarchy);
        });
}



 private void showHierarchy(String primary, List<TblCategory> u, CheckBoxTreeItem<String> cbtHierarchy) {
        if (primary.isEmpty()) {
            cbtParentName = new CheckBoxTreeItem<>(primary);
            cbtHierarchy.getChildren().add(cbtParentName);
        } else {
     showHierarchy(TblCategory.getParentID(), HierarchyServices.mapHierarchy().get(TblCategory.getParentID()), cbtHierarchy);
        }
    }
```

Please help me

Comment: *"Please help me!* Is neither a question, nor a problem statement. What is your problem/question?

Comment: HI sorry, my english is not good,I would like to help create recursive use menu map